# Unpivoting multicolumn table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this form (multiindex columns):

[MultiIndex Column Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBxeU.png)

and I would like to have it with this form:

| Date | Hour | Concept0 | Concept1 | Concept2 | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-29 | 1 | A | M | X | 0.1 |
| 2022-07-29 | 1 | A | M | Y | 0.2 |
| 2022-07-29 | 1 | A | N | W | 0.3 |
| 2022-07-29 | 1 | A | N | Z | 0.4 |

Thanks for your help

Comment: how are the elements of the two dataframes related ?

Comment: This looks like something that would be easier fixed by reading in the CSV correctly

Answer (score 0):

You must use from .melt method in pandas for unpivoting. Then you can rename the column names. It is very easy and just read melt docs in official pandas docs